# Wildcard text matching (joining) , what database system is best suited?

Tags: sql, text, statistics

I have a question for text analysis and database experts. I would like to match person names from one database table to text articles in another table. For example:

```
SELECT text FROM article 
INNER JOIN person
ON article.text LIKE "%" || person.name || "%"
```

This method is very slow on any database I tried, like Netezza, Redshift and traditional RDS's like MySQL or SQL server.

What system is best suited for queries like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is slow because you don't have an index and every query ends up in multiple full table scans. You can stay with a RDMBS if you like, the only thing you need to create is an index table

This table looks like this:

word varchar(n),
document_id int

The idea is to creaet for every word in a document one entry in this tabe where document_id points to the row in your source table

Then you create a db index in the word column and you end up with O(n log n) time complexity for your query

You can also try ibm db2 text search or similar tools from other vendors which basically are doing the same